# I received a letter with a mysterious "%" seal on the front

Tags: cipher

It was addressed to me, `U3Mg!y]lue!}98u.us`. The letter was dated 1969 and 1801.

The contents is as follows:

```
p\-HMyIqa`I\9)HP9g9a4<Mo%{u}qyu7u$q\4P%$!4%j]-MZa[%e]-aV%X474P%V]U\x]qMju_asH(!X5}!H9BubuQHx9Bak4PDLXp\(aZ%?5Q5\]0p_p<a?]4\d]qMtqDH(uj5-p(X$044(MFu{Iy]45X4d%$M5%?DSH\
```

The message is exactly half the length of the code, and starts and ends with a `"` character.

Comment: rot13(1969 = NFPVV, % naq 1801 = zbqhyb, c-\ = 20, U-\=20. Ab vqrn ubj lbh jbhyq ghea 112-92/72-92 gb 34, gubhtu. 18-yrggre "rznvy nqqerff" vf cebonoyl 'zbhfrgnvy', jvgu 'n' orvat 57-56)

Comment: The set of characters used for half of the code is suspicious, but I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: @codewarrior0 you might notice that, despite the start and the end being given to be the same character, they are encoded differently, yet there is a pattern.

Comment: I think they are in fact encoded identically. rot13(Vg ybbxf yvxr V unir cynva-pvcure rdhvinyragf va gur fnzr xrl sbe gur yrggref FGH ohg gur rapvcurevat sbezhyn vfa'g yvarne.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plaintext:

> ```
> "Beware of modular arithmetic, it will strike in 12 hours, or was it 12 hours ago?"
> ```

Solve path:

> I first noticed that there are fewer unique letters at the even positions of the text than at the odd positions. After listing the ASCII ordinals of those letters, I noticed a pattern: Each ordinal fits into one of five different groups according to the remainder after dividing by 20. In other words, there are only five different residue classes in this list.
>
> ```
>       33,  37, 45, 48,
>  52,  53,  57,     68,
>  72,  73,  77,     88,
>  92,  93,  97,
> 112, 113, 117
> ```

> Several false starts later, I had the hunch to apply modulo 20 to every ordinal in the text. I assumed each pair of values substituted a single letter and solved it as a simple substitution. (AZDecrypt gave me `REWARE OF HOPULAR ARITCHETIME` which was enough to complete the solution by hand.)

Substitution key:

> ```
>      32 (12,  0)
>   "  34 (12, 12)
>   ,  44 (12, 15)
>   1  49 ( 8, 16)
>   2  50 ( 8, 12)
>   3  51 ( 8,  8) ?
>   ....
>   ?  63 ( 8,  3)
>   B  66 ( 5, 12)
>   ....
>   a  97 (17, 16)
>   b  98 (17, 12) ?
>   c  99 (17,  8)
>   d 100 (17,  5)
>   e 101 (17,  1)
>   f 102 (17, 17)
>   g 103 (17, 13)
>   h 104 (17, 10)
>   i 105 (17,  6)
>   j 106 (17,  2) ?
>   k 107 (17, 18)
>   l 108 (17, 15)
>   m 109 (17, 11)
>   n 110 (17,  7)
>   o 111 (17,  3)
>   p 112 (13,  0) ?
>   q 113 (13, 16) ?
>   r 114 (13, 12)
>   s 115 (13,  8)
>   t 116 (13,  5)
>   u 117 (13,  1)
>   v 118 (13, 17) ?
>   w 119 (13, 13)
>
>              b
>         0  1  2  3
>
>   0     0 16 12  8
>   1     5  1 17 13
> a 2    10  6  2 18
>   3    15 11  7  3
> ```

> This key can be derived by writing the ASCII value in base 4 using four digits and dividing those digits into two groups of two digits each. Name the digits $ab$ and replace each group with the result of the formula $5a - 4b \pmod{20}$.
>
> ```
>    Char  Decimal  Base-4    Results
>    j     106      12, 22    17, 2
> ```

> To encipher a text, substitute each letter in the text with a pair of values as described above. Then, add an arbitrary multiple of 20 to each value in the list to bring it into the range of printable ASCII characters, and substitute the value with its corresponding character.

> To decipher a text, use the mysterious seal to recover the two digits from each letter's ASCII value: `%5` will recover $b$ and `%4` will recover $a$. Repeat the process for each letter in the cipher to recover four bits from each letter, which can be combined to recover the original text:

> [image: Deciphering function]

Comment: Very well done! Was not expecting anyone to answer it after all this time. The substitution uses a very simple formula and I'll accept if that part is figured out, small hint: rot13(dhnegre punenpgre)

Comment: =VM+I=4!I aQ4<] 9.a5%F5U\#\(9j!A45!D\Pa`4(5MM=5H!B (5X%jaG5(as%) (M9%S]\M[!e9Ka848